# What does it mean by "Is that still a thing"?

Tags: meaning

Someone asks "I want to know about your girl friend. Is that still a thing?" to his friend.

What does he exactly ask about? I don't understand. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 8):

"Is that still a thing?" is a way to ask "Is this still going on?" But generally speaking, people use it when they think something is ending. "[Still a thing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=still%20a%20thing)" is slang that is used when the subject is declining in popularity or has lost appeal. So you might say:

> Record players are still a thing?

referring to how record players are essentially useless with the advent of better technology (but are still around). Sarcastically one might say:

> Caring about celebrity lives is still a thing, huh?

referring to the cultural phenomenon of caring about celebrity lives and calling it irrelevant (even though it is not).

Your specific question needs more context. If someone says, "I want to know about your girlfriend. Is that still a thing?" they're asking if you still have a girlfriend (the "that" being your girlfriend), which in a broader sense means they're asking about your relationship status. Say you didn't have a girlfriend, but there's someone you like. If the asker knows about this person, "girlfriend" would be jokingly referring to the person you like as your girlfriend. "Is that a thing" could then mean "you still like her?" or "is she still not your girlfriend?"

Answer (score 4):

It means are you still in a relationship with your girlfriend.  Is that [the relationship] still a thing [a thing that is happening].  It is also used about popular trends - "downloading music, is that still a thing?" means "do people still download music?"